# Serving multiple servers on one domain without using subdomains on NGINX

Tags: nginx, web-server, reverse-proxy

I have searched and found many scenarios that are close, but I cannot get this to work properly. I have 2 servers running multiple apps. 1 server is running nginx as well as some other apps, and another server is running my pbx server. I want to use one domain to get to all of them, but not by using subdomains as I only want to use one SSL cert. Here is the latest config I have. The PBX is the issue. When I got to the locations https://pbx/pbx it returns the private IP address.

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;

       }

http{

upstream pbx
   {
    server 192.168.xxx.110;
   }

upstream admin 
   {
    server 192.168.xxx.61;
   }

server {

listen       443 ssl;
server_name  site.net;
error_log           /dir/ssl/logs/site.log;
ssl_certificate     /site/ssl/site.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /site/private.key;
ssl_ciphers         EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH;
ssl_protocols       TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

              location /admin {
                        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For 
                        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_pass https://admin/;
                        proxy_buffering off;
                        include  mime.types;
                          }
              location /pbx{
                        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For 
                        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_pass https://pbx/;
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                        proxy_buffering off;
                        include  mime.types;
                          }

      }

}
```

Comment: It's best to use subdomains for this, of course. Your comment about "I only want to use one SSL cert" doesn't make sense. You only need one SSL certificate.

Comment: Subdomains would require either a multi-domain cert or a wildcard cert. sub1.domain.com is not valid for a cert that is issued for domain.com.

Comment: A certificate with multiple domains is still a single SSL certificate. So this still doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm not sure why that matters. It's a file. It can be installed on multiple devices, but the url has to match to be valid. Subdomains break that.

Comment: You're still not making any sense. What is the "that" that "subdomains break"?

Comment: I explained it above. A cert is issued for a single domain unless it is a multi-domain cert or a wildcard cert. Those have to match in the URL. So sub.domain.com does not match a cert for domain.com and your browser will throw a warning. The subdomains can be added in the SAN field of the cert, but the only thing the cert issuer would add to mine is www, even though my CSR was written for all my subdomains.

Comment: OK, so you just have a problem with your cert issuer not doing what you asked them to do. There's no problem inherent in SSL certificates; you just need to go somewhere else to get them. Have you considered Let's Encrypt?

Comment: Yes, but I would rather not have to replace certs every 30 days. I can certainly do that. I know there are ways to make the cert work with subdomains, but I am looking for help on my problem above. That is not what I am trying to solve. I know how to do subdomains with multiple certs.